# Is there a simple way to add a service reference to one assembly but keep the client config in another?

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, assemblies, service-reference

I'm aware of the drawbacks of simply adding WCF service references (later I intend to create client proxies another way), but for now I need to add a service reference to a Silverlight assembly but the config to the main UI assembly so that it will be packaged into the `.xap` file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the app.config that gets created in a library when you add a service reference? If so they are only for reference and their settings need to be manually copied to the main UI app config.

Comment: You can add a copy of the client config file "Add - Add Existing Item - combobox at the Add button - Add as link". It will look as if there are two duplicated files but in reality they are just references to a single file.

Comment: HiTech - ServiceReferences.ClientConfig - but basically yeah. @vorrtex - that doesn't work because when the .xap is built it doesn't see the file when added as a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vorrtex in the comments turns out to be right. I lost sight of that solution after a bit of experimentation. I had also forgotten to mention that I was using the xml transformation tasks in the `.csproj` file.

My final solution is this:

1. In Silverlight service client assembly, add WCF references as usual.
2. Add a ServicesReferences.Configuration.ClientConfig for each build configuration
3. Add before/after build transform targets in the .csproj
4. Add as Link in the main Silverlight UI assembly.
5. Build. The Silverlight Web assembly creates the .xap for that configuration with the right ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file.